# Will current moderators be up for vote in the current pro tempore moderator election 2019?

Tags: support, election, moderators

In the [announcement](https://esperanto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/211/1576) of the [current "pro tempore" moderator election](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/election/1) (which has a separate meta "question" at [2019 Community Moderator Election](https://esperanto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212/2019-community-moderator-election)) Jon Ericson♦ wrote:

> (Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

What does that mean?

- Will current moderators automatically be candidates for the current election, without having to be nominated?

  or
- Will current moderators remain moderators in the current election, without having to be re-elected?

Or something else, yet?

As far as I understand, all moderator positions will be up for re-election in some later election (maybe even the one after the current one, whenever that will be), but I'm not even sure of that.

Is there some documentation that explains the election proccess(es) at large in more detail and the terms used like "graduation election"?

Answer (score 1):

> What does that mean?
>
> - Will current moderators automatically be candidates for the current election, without having to be nominated?
>
>   or
> - Will current moderators remain moderators in the current election, without having to be re-elected?
>
> Or something else, yet?

This is answered in [Experimenting with Pro Tempore elections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections):

> 4. Current moderators will not be required to nominate themselves—**they will continue as moderators unless they ask to step down.** (NB: Existing moderators currently get an email saying they must nominate themselves, but this is because the automated system does not yet know about pro tempore elections. Please ignore the instruction to nominate yourself if you get this email.)

(emphasis mine)

So **current moderators would remain moderators for now, without needing to be re-elected**. However, **of the current moderators only Neil will remain moderator** after this election as the other two current moderators *did* step down, according to Neil on telegram in group [Esperanto Language - Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.telegramo.org/):

> nur mi restos ĉar la aliaj du volonte foriras

---

> As far as I understand, all moderator positions will be up for
>   re-election in some later election (maybe even the one after the
>   current one, whenever that will be), but I'm not even sure of that.
>
> Is there some documentation that explains the election proccess(es) at
>   large in more detail and the terms used like "graduation election"?

How elections after the current one will work I still don't know yet.